# Get array with regex from string

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I got an php array like this:

```
array(3) {
   [0]=> string(12) "server[edit]" 
   [1]=> string(14) "server[create]" 
   [2]=> string(12) "user[delete]" 
}
```

I want to convert this to different arrays - for example an array named server with "edit" and "create" in it - and another array "user" with "delete".

Whats the right pattern for that ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you think regex is the tool for this job?

Comment: was my first idea, so it's possible to filter "server" and the action "edit" or "create" (but tbh i don't know how to) - is there another solution ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Looks like `^(\w+)\[(\w+)\]$` would be a good fit. But splitting this to different top-level arrays seems like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying a regex against the whole array, try matching against each individual value. Take a look at this as an example

```
$array = array(
        'server[edit]',
        'server[create]',
        'user[delete]',
        'dsadsa'
);

$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $value)
{
        preg_match("~^(\w+)\[(\w+)\]$~", $value, $matches);
        if(count($matches))
        {       
                $key = $matches[1];
                if(!isset($newArray[$key]))
                        $newArray[$key] = array();

                $newArray[$key][] = $matches[2];
        }
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Your `?` only applies to `\]` and the backslash is misplaced. I think you meant to write `~^(\w+)(?:\[(\w+)\])?$~`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Yeah, you're right about the ? and the \. I didn't want the ?: though, because I want the second capture to be value I insert into the arrays. I think that's what OP was aiming for

Comment: That's why I suggested `(?:`...`)` instead of `(`...`)`. But now I see you removed the `?` altogether.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Sorry, I might be a bit rusty on my regex, but doesn't ?: meant that the capture bracket won't be returned in $matches, so $matches[2] will return null or not be defined?

Comment: @Gareth no, it just doesn't count as a capture group, `$matches[2]` will still return the same thing. There would be no point in always returning `null` for a group.